# "Error validating client secret." 404 with Facebook Oauth and ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement facebook authentication for an app with warden, after the user allows facebook auth and redirects to my app callback with the token I get a 400 while consuming the api. My warden strategy is this:

```
class Facebook < Warden::Strategies::Base
  def client
    @client ||= OAuth2::Client.new MyApp::Facebook::AppID, MyApp::Facebook::AppSecret, :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com'
  end

  def params
    @params ||= Rack::Utils.parse_query(request.query_string)
  end

  def authorize_url
    client.web_server.authorize_url :redirect_uri => request.url, :scope => 'email,publish_stream'
  end

  def authenticate!
    throw(:halt, [302, {'Location' => authorize_url}, []]) unless params['code']
    facebook = client.web_server.get_access_token params['code'], :redirect_uri => request.url
  rescue OAuth2::HTTPError => e
    puts e.response.body
  end
end

Strategies.add :facebook, Facebook
```

The result of printing the response body is this:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating client secret."}}
```

I am pretty shure the app id and app secret are the ones provided by FB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've seen that error message many times. Here are the things I would double check:

- your domain is the same as what you listed in the facebook callback url
- the app id is correct (actually print this out on a page, sometimes y
- the app secret is correct

Comment: For me, it was using the wrong variable name from my config file :-/

Answer (score 1):

Add redirect_uri while creating the object of facebook that will fix the issue.

Redirect the user to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
After user click allow, it'll hit our Redirect Uri
At that point we'll get the code and we need to do a server side HTTP Get to the following Url to exchange the code with our oAuth access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&

```
 client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

Now at step 3, I kept on getting Http 400 response back.

So after some research, I found out that on that redirect_uri that we submitted on step 3 doesn't do anything but validate the request. Thus, the value need to match with step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same error and i resolved by doing as below:

1. double check your client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri.
2. Add Accept: "application/json" header to thye request

```
fetch(
    `https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=${process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=${process.env.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI}&client_secret=${process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET}&code=${code}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    }
  )
```